# igraph multicolor for a single vertex label text

Tags: r, igraph

This might be too much to ask, but is it possible to color only part of the label text? For example, I have a vertex with 2-line label, and I want the first line in black font and the second line in red font. Anything can be done?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can put the labels manually (if there is no other way).

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.atlas(sample(0:1252, 1))

layout1 <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g1)
plot(g1, layout = layout1)

layout2 <- apply(layout1, 2, function(x) {
  x <- x / (max(x)-min(x))*2
  x <- x - min(x) - 1
})

text(layout2[,1], layout2[,2], pos = 3, labels = letters[1:length(V(g1))], col ="red" )
```

[image]