# Custom node drawing function in igraph / R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

In the package Rgraphviz, it is possible to pass a custom function drawing the nodes as an argument to the plot(). This allows to construct any arbitrarily complex subplot for each of the nodes.

I am looking for one of the following:

1) how to pass a custom node-drawing function to plotting function of igraph, or

2) how to create a layout with igraph and than plot it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any custom function parameter in plot function.
But you can combine igraph plot with your own creation. See answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148318/igraph-multicolor-for-a-single-vertex-label-text/29149942) to see how to use layout coordinates.

If you want to pack everything in the `plot`, you could define your class and a special plot method. Maybe also use `NextMethod` to combine with the original plot.

### Update

See the answer from Gabor Csardi about vertex shapes.

Comment: igraph has vertex shapes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

igraph supports vertex shapes. You cannot change the labels themselves, but you can just omit the labels, and add them from your custom vertex shape code. See examples here:
http://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph.vertex.shapes.html